# Rotating around completely in 90 degree intervals

Tags: actionscript, rotation

I have a circular menu that rotates 90 degrees every time leftArrow_mc is clicked but at 270 degrees the button stops working. Also will the reseting the degrees back to 0 do anything for me?

```
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;

    leftArrow_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotateLeft1);

    function rotateLeft1(event: MouseEvent):void {
if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation==0) {
    TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 90, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
} else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 90) {
    TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 180, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
} else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 180) {
    TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 270, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
} else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 270) {
    TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 360, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
}
else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 360) {
    bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 0
}
```

}

Comment: should note: if the answer helps solve your problems you should accept the answer or people will be unlikely to help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres your answer, it works.. If you need the working let me know..its late so im not sure why this behaves like it does but i would check into the property (rotation:) inside your tweens.

```
      import com.greensock.*;
      import com.greensock.easing.*;

     leftArrow_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotateLeft1);

     function rotateLeft1(event: MouseEvent):void {
      if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation==0) {
      TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 90, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
      } else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 90) {
      TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 180, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
      } else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == 180) {
      TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 270, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
      } else if (bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation == -90) {
      TweenLite.to(bottomWheel_menu_mc, 1, {rotation: 0, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
      }
       trace( bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that works perfectly! so does actionscript not allow values over 270 degrees? and now im trying to create the same script with a right arrow (turning counter clockwise). im getting a similar problem. i am going:
0->-90
270->180
180->90
90->0

Comment: but i did the same exact thing you wrote just in reverse

Comment: no it didnt work, ive tried all sorts of combinations but if, for example, i substitute -90 for 270 flash doesnt realize it yet that worked perfectly fine in the other function